# How can I reset permissions when testing on a real iPhone?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

Story: I am working on a project and it includes a custom camera(like on Snapchat or Instagram). I set it up to ask for permission before using the camera, and I ran it on my actual iPhone instead of the simulator, because the simulator would crash since it doesn’t have a camera. I needed to change some code after I had allowed the camera to be used and now every time I run the app, everything is messed up. I know that the permission is the issue because when I run the app on my simulator (which I never gave the permission in) and it works fine.

Question: on the simulator you can just press erase all content and settings, which would also reset the permission. I used my personal iPhone to run it since i did not foresee this issue. So obviously I am not going to erase all content and settings on my iPhone, but I am wondering if there’s another way to reset the permission. (I have already reset location and privacy settings on my iPhone but that did not reset the permission.)

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the app. That should clear all permissions, including camera, notifications, etc.

Comment: I have done that multiple times without any luck. It seems that somehow the app is leaving something behind even when I press erase app and the apps documents. That’s why I wished I had installed it on a phone that I could just reset all content and settings on.  Any other ideas are welcome :)

Comment: That is strange, as far as I know it resets all permissions. What is the issue exactly? You want to clear the camera permissions and show the UI to ask for permissions again?

Comment: I agree it is strange. The exact issue is that when I run the app, the UI is messed up. I would like it to ask for camera permissions again which will fix that. I do however, have it running on another device now which is working fine, since it never had the permission before the issue was fixed. I would still like to get the UI to ask for permission again on the device that is not working.